# SharePoint 2010 - Checking out multiple documents issue

Tags: 2010, document-library, check-out

I have a user that has IE8 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, they are trying to check-out multiple documents at the same time by selecting all documents and the selecting Check Out up in the Documents tab.  The 'Checking Out...' ajax notification pops up, but nothing is checked out.  If he tries to check out a single document it works some of the time from the 'Check Out' option on the documents tab.

We have emptied the OfflineFileCache, cleared the Internet Explorer Cache, Tried repairing the office installation, and installed SharePoint Designer 32-bit to add the SharePoint support package.

Not sure what other troubleshooting steps need to take place.

Comment: Probably the error lays in the usage of IE 64bit instead of 32bit

Comment: I verified that he was using the 32-bit version of IE8.